# Programmatically distinguish hardware wallet

Tags: web3.js, wallet, ledger

Is it possible to programmatically tell the difference between a hot wallet and a hardware wallet with @solana/web3.js? I would like some features to be available only for Ledger users.

Comment: If somebody had a hardware wallet imported into say Phantom, what behaviour would you want? Should they get the ledger-only features or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@solana/web3.js don't have any functionality to communicate with browser and hardware wallets, so the answer to your question is no.

But please look into the wallet-adapter instead as that is the recommended package for communicating with most wallets and hardware wallets including ledger: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter

In a hardware wallet such as ***Ledger*** the private key always stays on the device and is non-extractable. So in order for a hardware wallet to sign a request you must send an unsigned transaction to the hardware wallet and request it to sign it.

If you can't touch/extract the private key it's safe to say you're working with a hardware wallet.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you'd determine if you can extract the private key? AFAIK browser wallets absolutely shouldn't be exposing an API to get the private key as a dapp, and wallet-adapter doesn't. Hardware wallets are more secure, but not because browser wallets expose the private key to dapps as a matter of course.

Comment: Since hardware wallets can either create their own account, or import existing accounts created by hot wallets, I also figured there is no way to distinguish between them.

@CallumM, dApps can never extract private keys from any wallet. In fact the only way to get a hardware wallet's private key is to derive it from the mnemonic seed phrase.

Comment: That is indeed a very good question. Unfortunately I do not have enough knowledge about how browser wallets works internally. You're definitely right, there is no way browser wallets would expose this over an API.